# multiple tab blocks on one page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make tabs that can be reused on the page. I've seen examples of an id named tab1 corresponding with where the contents id is named tabContent1, but the content will be loaded in dynamically so I have no control on how many tabs there will be on the page. I have the structure of how I would like the html set out that would be reused through the page, but no idea on how to build the js. Ultimately all content tabs would be closed on page load and then once a tab is clicked it would slide down the corresponding content.

```
<div class="tabContainer">
    <div class="tabMenu">
        <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
    </div><!-- class="tabMenu" -->
    <div class="tabContent">
        <div class="tabBlock">Tab Content 1</div>
        <div class="tabBlock">Tab Content 2</div>
        <div class="tabBlock">Tab Content 3</div>
    </div><!-- class="tabContent" -->
</div><!-- class="tabContainer" -->
```

If the html structure has to be re-structured that is fine.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest use jqueryui tabs, check it out at here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Yea like I said, the problem with that is I don't have the capability to add an id name to every content div, because the content will be inserted through back-end coding and I don't know how many there will be. I was hoping someone would know a way of getting the same numbered tab div to open the same numbered content div. i.e. when div.tab:first clicked, open div.tabBlock:first